# Using Ajax to not reload new page with errors in login form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a login form where I used ajax to catch the login errors i.e. "incorrect password" from my login.php, and to display them onto the same login form rather than reloading a new page with the error message. That now works fine, but when the login IS successful it now loads the entire logged in page (home.php) onto the login form rather than loading it to a new page! You can see in the picture here, [image: AJAX LOGIN PROBLEM]. Here is my code for the ajax I have used:

```
   $("#login_button").click(function(){

    $.post($("#login_form").attr("action"), $("#login_form :input").serializeArray(), function(info){$("#login_errors").html(info);});
    // Prevent the default action from occurring.
    return false;
});

$("login_form").submit(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Here is the code for my login form that I have used:

```
<form id= "login_form" action="login.php" method="post">
<span id="login_errors" style="color:#F00;"></span>
<label>Email Address</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required"/>
<br />

<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="required"/>
<br />

<div class="checkbox">
<input id="remember" type="checkbox" name="keep" />
<label for="remember">Keep me signed in</label>
</div>

<div class="action_btns">
<div class="one_half last"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-blue" id="login_button" value="Login"></div>
<div class="one_half last"><a href="#" id="register_form" class="btn">Sign up</a></div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `function(info){$("#login_errors").html(info);}` part of your `$.post()` - the success callback - is taking whatever output your login.php is generating (`info`), and inserting it into the element with id login_errors (presumably the bottom part of your login form).

If you want the user to be bounced on to a new page, you need to update your success callback to handle that.  For example, on success your login.php could do something like:

```
if (... login-success test ... ) {
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'Login failed, pls try again';
}
```

Then your success callback can check that output and react accordingly, like:

```
if (info === 'OK') {
   // login.php says login succeeded, bounce user to dashboard
   window.location.href = 'http://successful/login/url';
} else {
   // login.php says login failed, show the output it gave us
    $("#login_errors").html(info)
}
```

Comment: $("#login_button").click(function(){

    $.post($("#login_form").attr("action"), $("#login_form :input").serializeArray(), function(info){if (info.status === 'ok') {
   window.location.href = home.php;
} else {
    $("#login_errors").html(info)
};});
    // Prevent the default action from occurring.
    return false;
});

Comment: but still doing the same thing

Comment: Did you update your login.php too?  The example code I posted and which you are now using assumes login.php is outputting a JSON response with status, destination and/or message.  Output can be anything you want, it is up to you, but the success callback needs to handle whatever you generate.

Comment: oh ok, no i didn't change my login.php yet. How would I output a json status response? sorry, I am very new to all of this

Comment: ok, ill give it a go cheers. and does 'info' automatically catch whatever login.php produces? i don;t need to declare a variable called info in my login.php or anytuing do i?

Comment: No, you don't need to use info in your login.php, and it can be called anything in your JS.  [The jQuery $.post() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) have more examples.  If my answer helped, pls consider accepting and/or upvoting, thanks!